# Elementary symmetric functions of a number field embedding

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, symmetric-polynomials

I am trying to understand Dirichlet's Unit Theorem and I come across to a part that I do not have any idea. I will write down the arguments and then ask my question:

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n=r_1 + 2r_2$ where $r_1$ denotes the number of real embedding of $K$ and $2r_2$ is the number of complex embeddings of $K$. Since complex emdeddings come in pairs, we can consider only the *first* $r_1$ one: $\sigma_{r_1+1},\dots,\sigma_{r_1+r_2}$. Let us define now the homomorphism 
$$\sigma:K \to \mathbb{R}^{r_1+r_2} ; 
\sigma(x)=(|\sigma_1(x)|,\dots,|\sigma_{r_1+r_2}(x)|).$$

*My aim is to show that the image of units in $\mathcal{O}_K$  under $\sigma$ is a discrete subgroup of $ \mathbb{R}^{r_1+r_2}$*.

Now, let us take a compact subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^{r_1+r_2}$. Set $B'$ to be the set $\{x \in \mathcal{O}_K: \sigma(x) \in B\}$. Since $B$ is bounded, so is $B'$. So I can find some $\epsilon$-ball in $\mathbb{R}^{r_1+r_2}$ so that $B$ fits in it. Which also means that the norm of elements of $B$ is bounded.

With this information, I can find some $\alpha >1$ such that  for each $x \in B'$, $\alpha^{-1} \le |\alpha_i(x)| \le \alpha, (i=1,\dots,n)$-here, the book says $n$ but I guess it should be $r_1+r_2$.-

Finally, the part that I do not understand comes:

> *It follows that the elementary symmetric functions of $\sigma_i(x)$'s are bounded in absolute value. Since they belong to $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of possible values for the symmetric functions of the $\sigma_i(x)$'s is a finite set.*

It seems like we can write for each $i$, $\sigma_i(x)=p_1(x) \times \dots \times p_k(x)$ where $k \le n$, $p_i(x)$'s are  symmetric functions. So we can get the result, but how?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the characteristic polynomial of $x$, which is

$$ \Phi_x(t) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (t - \sigma_i(x)).$$

(Here we are also considering the entire Galois group rather than just half of the complex embeddings.) If $\mu_x(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ then $\Phi_x(t) = \mu_x(t)^{[K:\mathbf{Q}(x)]}$. Both polynomials belong to $\mathbf{Z}[t]$ since $x \in \mathcal O_K$.

We can alternatively write

$$\Phi_x(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^{n - k} e_{n - k}(x) t^k $$

where

$$ e_k(x) = \sum_{1 \le i_1 < \cdots < i_k \le n} \sigma_{i_1}(x) \cdots \sigma_{i_k}(x). $$

We call $e_0(x), \dots, e_n(x)$ the elementary symmetric functions in $\sigma_1(x), \dots, \sigma_n(x)$.

Since $\Phi_x(t) \in \mathbf{Z}[t]$ we can say that $e_k(x) \in \mathbf{Z}$. Since  $\sigma_1(x),\dots,\sigma_n(x)$ are bounded, so are $e_0(x),\dots,e_n(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do we alternatively write the polynomial $\Phi_x(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^{n - k} e_k(x) t^k $?

Comment: @Ninja Sorry, that should have been an $e_{n - k}$. Suppose you have $(t - a)(t - b)$ you can write that as $t^2 - (a + b)t + ab$ where $e_0 = 1$, $e_1 = a + b$ and $e_2 = ab$. For $(t - a)(t - b)(t - c)$ you can write it as $t^3 - (a + b + c)t^2 + (ab + ac + bc)t - abc$ where $e_0 = 1$, $e_1 = a + b + c$, $e_2 = ab + ac + bc$ and $e_3 = abc$. If you do this for $\Phi_x(t)$ then $e_0 = 1$, $e_1 = \operatorname{Tr}_{K}(x)$ and $e_n = \operatorname{N}_K(x)$.

Comment: The reason they are called "symmetric functions" is because if you permute say $a, b, c$ then the functions $e_0 = 1, e_1 = a + b + c, e_2 = ab + ac + bc, e_3 = abc$ are unaffected.

Comment: Okay. Then, do we see the conjugates $\sigma_i(x)$  as variables? Since if we say that the variable is $X$, then we can only talk about one variable.

Comment: @Ninja If I understand you correctly, then yes. If $n = 3$ then $e_0(x) = 1$, $e_1(x) = \sigma_1(x) + \sigma_2(x) + \sigma_3(x)$, $e_2(x) = \sigma_1(x)\sigma_2(x) + \sigma_1(x)\sigma_3(x) + \sigma_2(x)\sigma_3(x)$ and $e_3(x) = \sigma_1(x)\sigma_2(x)\sigma_3(x)$.

Comment: Okay, let me think on the answer.

Comment: It may be trivial but still, I can not see why $\Phi_x(t) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (t - \sigma_i(x)).$ is the characteristic polynomial of $x$?

Comment: @Ninja If $A_x : K \to K$ is the $\mathbf{Q}$-linear map $A_x(y) = xy$ then the minimal polynomial of $A_x$ is just the minimal polynomial of $x$. If we put $A_x$ into rational canonical form then $A_x$ is a direct sum of companion matrices corresponding to a sequence $q_1 \mid q_2 \mid \cdots \mid q_r$ where $q_r$ is the minimal polynomial of $A_x$. But now $q_1(A_x)$ is singular and corresponds to multiplication by $q_1(x)$. Since we are in a field, either $q_1(x) = 0$ or $q_1(x)$ is invertible. Therefore $q_1(A_x)$ is singular implies $q_1(x) = 0$. So $q_1 = q_r$ is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Which means that $q_1 = q_2 = \cdots = q_r = \mu_x =$ the minimal polynomial of $x$ and hence the characteristic polynomial of $A_x$ is $q_r^r$. On the other hand, $\prod_{\sigma \in G} (t - \sigma(x)) = \left(\prod_{\sigma(x) \in G.x} (x - \sigma(x)) \right)^{|G_x|} = \mu_x(t)^{|G_x|}$ by orbit-stabilizer decomposition. By degree counting, $r = |G_x| = [K : \mathbf{Q}(x)]$.

Comment: I keep asking questions but I just wonder why we do not have the terms $\sigma_i(x)^n$ for all $i$ in $e_n$?

Comment: @Ninja With $\sigma_1(x)$, for example, we can write $$ (t - \sigma_1(x))(t - \sigma_2(x)) \cdots (t - \sigma_n(x)) \\ = \underbrace{t(t - \sigma_2(x)) \cdots (t - \sigma_n(x))}_{\text{no copies of $\sigma_1(x)$}} - \sigma_1(x) \underbrace{(t - \sigma_2(x)) \cdots (t - \sigma_n(x))}_{\text{no copies of $\sigma_1(x)$}} $$ and from this decomposition we can see that there can be at most one copy of $\sigma_1(x)$ in any given term.